# K-medoids clustering with Gower distance in R

Tags: r, clustering, gower-similarity

I have both numeric and binary data in my data set with 73 observations.
I read a lot about which distance metric and which clustering technique to use especially from this web site.
I decided to use Gower distance metrics and K-medoids.
In R, I used package "cluster", and function "daisy" with metric="gower".
So I got a 73*73 matrix.
Now, as I understood, this is not a distance matrix, it is a similarity matrix that I am confused what to do after now.
I use function pam: pam(x, k, diss = inherits(x, "dist")...
Should I use the 73*73 matrix which I got from daisy function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation of the `pam` function, which implements K-medoids.

> In case of a dissimilarity matrix, `x` is typically the output of `daisy` or `dist`.

and the documentation of `daisy`:

> “Gower's distance” is chosen by metric `"gower"` or automatically if some columns of x are not numeric. Also known as Gower's coefficient (1971), **expressed as a dissimilarity**, this implies that a particular standardisation will be applied to each variable, and the “distance” between two units is the sum of all the variable-specific distances, see the details section.

The documentation of R is pretty good... use it.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that, the matrix I got from daisy with Gower, is not a dissimilarity matrix so I need to use other function to have distance matrix before applying pam. Then, I'm confused sorry, what about diss in pam function? It is TRUE in my case I think. And I couldn't understand also metric=euclidean in pam function, because I used Gower distance...

Comment: Yes you are right Anony-Mousse, thank you so much. I am reading, studying, trying to understand everything, sometimes confused.

Comment: The examples here (http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/Cluster2a.html) are also good answer for my question